# Testing Debugging in Offline Mode via Network

Tags: ios, cordova, offline-caching

I'm developing a hybrid cordova app that should work offline as well. It just caches the data fetched from the network and re-uses the cached version if offline.

Since it's a cordova app, the dev files are on my machine and the url embedded in the app is pointed to my machine, so turning on airplane mode will stop the app to even pull the source code files to start with.

I'm trying to find out what's the approach to develop and test the offline behavior as you code.

Answer (score 3):

Install [Additional Tools for XCode 8.2](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Additional_Tools_for_Xcode_8.2/Additional_Tools_for_Xcode_8.2.dmg) . This is a network link conditioner. You can simulate many number of network conditions for your device with this.

More about [Network Link Conditioner](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/)

List of all additional tools is [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=for%20Xcode) which includes Additional tool for all versions of xcode.

Comment: but that's for simulator based development, the iPad device in this case is accessing internet directly. Thanks for the enlightenment though.

Comment: See how to use it on iPad/iPhone device http://www.thomashanning.com/network-link-conditioner/. Scroll to bottom

Comment: I could see the Developer setting on iPhone but can't on iPad, I updated iPad as well. (version 11.1.1)

Comment: You have to install the app using cable and then the developer mode gets enabled on device

Comment: There's a catch, if I turn on network link conditioner to 100% loss, I can't even load files from network. (source code resides on my dev machine and I'm executing code on the device as I develop), seem the only way is to pull the internet plug

Comment: Put a breakpoint at a point where all the files are loaded. And simulate  100% loss post that point. Not sure if you require continuous access to remote File system or one time access.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off your wifi connection and proceed(or LAN connection) while testing.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But my service call did spin for about 1 minute until it gave up, is that normal?

Comment: That's normal thing, I guess. Can't say much as without knowledge on your code base and environment.